# Having a hard time finding a graphic engine programmer

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics-programming, hiring

I'm looking for a graphic engine programmer that knows both OpenGL and software rendering code to hire for a very short period (2 days). It's urgent and I'm willing to pay a very high amount of money. Any ideas where I could find one keeping in mind the points mentioned below?

**Clarifications**

1. I am not specifically looking for significant expertise, even intermediate knowledge in OpenGL and software rendering engine code will do.
2. I do not represent a company therefore I can't use gamasutra jobs, stackoverflow careers, etc.

Comment: Why not just learn and become one yourself? That's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of project that requires significant expertise you can actually do in 2 days, but your best bet is to probably look at the resumes posted on the gamasutra jobs board.

http://www.gamasutra.com/jobs/

Comment: I am not specifically looking for significant expertise and I can't use the gamasutra jobs section. Added clarifications in the original post.

Comment: Why not? Just make an account and send mails to the guys. Where is the problem? Probably you dont even need an account.

Comment: Well if you want to do the resume search it's going to cost you.  http://www.jointhegamenetwork.com/recruitment/online/resume.html

Answer (score 0):

try http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try: [OpenGL Job Classifieds](http://www.opengl.org/jobs/)